# Display Tumblr Demo Posts as Sample Posts?

Tags: html, css, tumblr, tumblr-themes

I wondered if there is a way to use the posts that I've put in my Demo Tumblr Theme as the 'Sample Posts' in Tumblr for when someone downloads and installs the theme?

I know that when you install a theme and go to customise it, there is an option to use your 'own posts' or 'sample posts' and I'd like to be able to set it up so that the posts I've used in my Demo for the theme, display instead of the standard ones provided by Tumblr.

Does anyone know if this is possible and/or any tutorials/suggestions on how to go about doing it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sadly not, for the reasons you stated. The only options are the sample or own posts.

Comment: Why show sample posts on the user's Tumblr? Just place a link to your demo blog

Comment: It is possible as it is done with [this theme](https://www.tumblr.com/theme/38922) but I cannot work out what does it.